# Need a basic understanding of the sqlplus command

Tags: sql, unix

sqlplus -s £ORA_LOGIN/£ORA_PASSWORD @./sql/getsess.sql £FEED > £FEED.lst

This is the command in a shell script. Can anyone please tell me what is this doing? because i have no knowledge about the sqlplus command

Comment: The very first result I got from Google for "sqlplus" was this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/qstart.htm I'm sure if you look further down the results, you'll find lots of other help pages and examples too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the information is already readily available.

Answer (score 0):

This command runs the script *./sql/getsess.sql* providing the value *£FEED* as parameter and using the credentials *£ORA_LOGIN/£ORA_PASSWORD* to login. It will store the output from the call to SQLPlus in the file named *£FEED.lst*.

Note that SQLPlus is invoked in silent mode (parameter *-S*), so most of the output will not be seen in the output file.